# Create a file using variables for the file name java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a file and save the file as a name given as input and the iteration number. But this isn't writing anything to the source folder. I don't know where I could be going wrong.

```
private void write() throws IOException {
        File file = new File(name + it_number + ".txt");
        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

        writer.write(results);

        it_number++;
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
}
```

Comment: For starters, where is `name` actually being defined?  Also, if your code is executing without any visible errors, then one possibility is that you are writing to a folder which you don't expect.  To remedy this, you can use the full system path to the file you want to write.

Comment: I hope you are using java project,if so then it will create file in the project directory not in source folder

Comment: your code should work... where are you saving the file???

Comment: Also read up on [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix, but a debug hint - to find where the file is going to be written:

```
File file = new File(name + it_number + ".txt");
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use BufferedWriter as below

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(results);
bw.close();
```